# powershell reading registry

Tags: powershell, registry

i have the following reg path andI know it exists, am I doing something wrong here?!

```
$path = 'Registry::HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000001'
Get-ChildItem $path | Get-ItemProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Service Name"
```

pshell returns :

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000001'
because it does not exist.
```

Comment: Have you tried to do a get-childitem on the parent folder? Does the 00000001 appears?

Answer (score 1):

On my machine that key exists in HKCU and HKU, not HKLM. Can you give this a try:

```
$path = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000001'
Get-ItemProperty $path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Service Name"
```

Get-ChildItem only returns subkeys in registry, so it wouldn't return anything for this path. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176852.aspx